# How to add a common suffix to multiple variables?

Tags: matlab

I have a list of variables in the workspace. For example;

```
C_CA1xDG_1
C_GPxDG_5
C_CA1xDG_B
C_CA1xDG_iB
C_DGxDG_PS
C_CPxDG_CS
C_CA1xDG_1
```

I would to add a common suffix (`_A12`) at the end of these variables' names, so the results would be;

```
C_CA1xDG_1_A12
C_CA1xDG_5_A12
C_CA1xDG_B_A12
C_CA1xDG_iB_A12
C_DGxDG_PS_A12
C_CPxDG_CS_A12
C_CA1xDG_1_A12
```

I would be glad if somebody could help me.

Comment: The short answer is: don’t do this! Don’t use program-generated variable names, it leads to obscure bugs and complicated code. Use cell arrays or struct arrays to structure your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really bad practise to have dynamically/programmatically assigned variable names. Much better would be to store your variables in a cell array or, if you want to preserve some naming, a struct.

Let's imagine you had all of those variables in a struct

```
myStruct = struct();
myStruct.C_CA1xDG_1 = [1 2 3];
myStruct.C_GPxDG_5  = [4 5 6];
% ...
myStruct.C_CPxDG_CS = 'CPxDG_CS!!';
```

Now you can do a number of things easily.

- Instead of applying a suffix to the field names, why not just nest the struct?

  ```
  myNestedStruct = struct();
  myNestedStruct.A12 = myStruct;
  ```

  And you can access things neatly like `myNestedStruct.A12.C_CA1xDG_1`.

  This is useful if your motivation for adding the suffix was to have similar names with other suffixes - now just have more fields in the containing struct!
- If you really want to rename the fields, you can do that too. This is a bit messy, but not nearly as bad as dynamic workspace variable names because they're easy to manipulate, contain, and check the existence of...

  ```
  f = fieldnames( myStruct );
  for ii = 1:numel(f)
      myStruct.( [f{ii}, '_A12'] ) = myStruct.( f{ii} );
      rmfield( myStruct, f{ii} );
  end
  ```

  Note, here I'm using the syntax for indexing a struct field with a string, which requires the string to be surrounded by brackets.

Comment: I wrote a function `mvfield` a long time ago, which does something similar to this.  http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/MATLAB.html